# How to invoke a method on remote object, in python?

Tags: python-3.x, factory-method

I have a windows machine, where i am trying to generate n number of files, specified through yaml.

client = SSH(hostname='zzzz', username='zz', password='yy')

client.trafficflow.run(args)

class Trafficflow()
    def **init**(self, client, **kwargs):
        self.client = client

```
def run(self, **kwargs):
#Has the code to generate the directory and write files,like below
    os.makedirs(dirname)
    f = open(directory_create + ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 8)) + database_type)
    f.seek(int(file_size))
    f.write(("end of file").encode())
f.close()
```

But the above code works only on the machine, where this script is executed.Is there any way, i can invoke the method on the client bject, so that i see the folders and files on the remote machine?Please help?

Comment: please edit your text appropriately and include all the relevant info, e.g. where does SSH come from?

Comment: Anyways, i use paramiko , to get the client object..Its ssh object.There is a method, i have written, which returns the client object.